# handling two simultaneous request in node/mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have two services - ServiceA (PHP), ServiceB (Express/Mongo)

There are two instances under an ELB for ServiceA. ServiceA has to send a request to serviceB to complete the transaction. 
Somehow, serviceA is calling one request each from those two instances at the same time.

Now at ServiceB there is a check while saving the request if it previously exists in DB. Somehow, it created two entries for the same request (at the same time).

Now to prevent this: 
If I add the unique constraint on the requestId from serviceA, will it prevent from saving two same requests?

How does node and mongo process simultaneous request??

Comment: Instead of trying to fix symptoms, why not try to fix the cause, namely that ServiceA is calling ServiceB twice where it should only call it once?

Comment: Yes, we are trying to debug that. But, still, I want to know how does node/express handle simultaneous request?

Comment: This article explains the Node.js event loop: http://blog.mixu.net/2011/02/01/understanding-the-node-js-event-loop/